# Hypergeometric Distribution Doesn't Apply in This Case?

Tags: probability

**Cards are dealt without replacement from a standard deck of cards until a heart is dealt.**

**1.    What is the probability that exactly 5 cards are required?**

Here I thought about using geometric distribution. I thought of this question as drawing 5 cards without replacement and we get exactly 4 non-heart cards and 1 red card.

the setup I have is $\frac {\binom {39}{4} \binom {13}{1}}{\binom {52}{5}}$ However this answer is different from the solution given. I also thought about using negative binomial distribution but it shouldn't apply to this case since the trials are not independent ?

**2.    What is the probability that 5 or fewer cards are required?**

Here the solution given is 1-(39/52)(38/51)(37/50)(36/49)(35/48).
I don't understand why the compliment of P(5 non heart cards) = P(5 or fewer cards are required), should the compliment of P(5 non-heart cards) be at least one heart card in 5 draws?

**3.    Given that exactly 5 cards are required, what is the probability that 3 spades were dealt?**

For this question should I use Bayes Theorem or the standard conditional probability setup?

Using the standard setup I got $ P(B|A)= \frac {P(A and B)}{P(A)} = \frac {\frac {13}{52} \frac {12}{51} \frac {11}{50} \frac {26}{49} \frac {13}{48}}{\frac {13}{52}\frac {12}{51}\frac {11}{50}}$ I know this is wrong somehow but I can't figure out how else to solve this problem.

Thank you!!

Comment: You should first consider whether the order in which you draw the cards matters.

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe How could this matter? I do not understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It equals the probability that a heart is dealt in the first $5$ cards minus the probability that a heart is dealt in the first $4$ cards. Both can be calculated using hypergeometric distribution.

2) It equals the probability that a heart is dealt in the first $5$ cards and can be calculated using hypergeometric distribution. Actually we met this probability in 1) already, so it is better first to solve 2) and then 1). You can also find it as $1$ minus the probability that no hearts are dealt in the first $5$ cards.

3) You could find the probabilities on $SSSXH,SSXSH,SXSSH,XSSSH$ where $S$ stands for spades, $H$ for hearts and $X$ for other than spades or hearts. Then addition of these probabilities gives you the probability that *exactly* $3$ spades were drawn. If you want the probabilitiy that *at least* $3$ spades were drawn then you must add the probability on $SSSSH$.

Comment: Thank you Vera, for # 3 the combination should be $\binom {5}{3}$ for the number of ways to arrange SSSXH right?

Comment: $P(SSSXH)=\frac{13}{52}\frac{12}{51}\frac{11}{50}\frac{26}{49}\frac{13}{48}$. You must take this $\binom43=4$ times since $P(SSSXH)=P(SSXSH)=P(SXSSH)=P(XSSSH)$. There are exactly $5$ cards dealt so the $5$-th card must be the first hearts.

Answer (score 1):

1) Your $\frac {\binom {39}{4} \binom {13}{1}}{\binom {52}{5}}$ is the probability of choosing $4$ non-hearts and $1$ heart in $5$ picks, but does not impose an order.  You actually want the heart to be fifth of five, so need to divide that by $5$.  Alternatively calculate $\frac {39}{52} \frac {38}{51} \frac {37}{50} \frac {36}{49} \frac {13}{48}$

2)  *At least one heart card in five draws* has the same probability as *five or fewer draws needed to get the first heart*

3) It is not the easiest way to do it, but your Bayesian calculation should be $\frac {4 \frac {13}{52} \frac {12}{51} \frac {11}{50} \frac {26}{49} \frac {13}{48}}{\frac {39}{52} \frac {38}{51} \frac {37}{50} \frac {36}{49} \frac {13}{48}}$ using the result from (1) and taking into account that the card which is neither a spade nor a heart can be any of the first four cards.  If you want an answer to "*at least* thee spades" then add $\frac {\frac {13}{52} \frac {12}{51} \frac {11}{50} \frac {10}{49} \frac {13}{48}}{\frac {39}{52} \frac {38}{51} \frac {37}{50} \frac {36}{49} \frac {13}{48}}$

Comment: Thank you Henry #1 and #2 makes sense to me now, however for #3 How did you get the 4 in the numerator ?

Comment: @pino231 "the card which is neither a spade nor a heart can be any of the first four cards"